# Wordpress theme is missing css on server, has only HTML

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

My site was working ok until half an hour ago. http://spi.ba/

It looks like it is missing plugins, css, js. First I noticed it was missing revolution slider and I thought it was related to licence for slider, but 10 minutes after that whole site lost css and js.

What might be a problem? 
Thanks,

Comment: are you using a caching plugin? if yes, clear the cache - also do you use plugins to minify css or js?

Comment: Yes, I was using wp super cache plugin. I deactivated it and site started working normaly. Thank you very much. I use autooptimize plugin only. I don't use other to minify css or js. 
I need cache plugin. What to do now? Will this happen again if I activate it?

Comment: I would recommend signing up for a free account at Cloudflare instead of using a plugin for caching. This requires you re-route your DNS through Cloudflare nameservers, but it is pretty easy as long as you have access to your domain's DNS settings.

Answer (score 0):

You should upload the missing file to your live server or you should re-upload whole source code of site on your live server.

Check the result once the whole source code will be uploaded to the server.